# systemd.mount : x-systemd.device-ut?

Tags: systemd, automount, nfs

In some source about nfs mounting (sorry I have lost the reference) I found information that led to this fstab setting that raises no error but which I do not understand completely.

```
10.0.0.110:/export/usb2T /mnt/usb2T nfs nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-ut=10 0 0
```

The part I don't understand is the `x-systemd.device-ut`. Google does not find it without `-ut` and it doesn't grep out of any of the systemd man pages I've tried.

What is it about?

Answer (score 1):

`x-systemd-ut` should be `x-systemd-timeout`.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd.mount.5.html

This was either a typo or paste error from the original source. I don't understand why it didn't throw an error.